# Daemon under linux fails to launch app with execv

Tags: linux, daemon, execv

We have a command and control daemon running under Fedora 16 that provides various services, including starting one of our ancillary applications.  This has been working for us for quite some time.

In fact it still works - on some systems.

The daemon process forks (successfully) and then calls execv().

Setting up on another system to test, I suddenly have a failure, and execv() fails and returns 127.

Both systems are running Fedora 16, although the one with the problem is 3.3.7-1.fc16.x86_64 whereas another where everything works fine is running 3.4.2-1.fc16.x86_64

If I stop the daemon and run it as a stand-alone application, the whole process works fine.

All searching through documentation on execv() and related fails to bring up a 127 error code, my only guess so far is the Linux 'Command not found' error.  Not knowing what it means is making it hard to fix the problem.

Can anybody tell me what the 127 return code means?

Thanks!

Comment: "command not found" is a good place to start :)  Q: What command are you trying to exec?  Q: Does it fail consistently on the systems that aren't working, or just intermittantly?  Q: Any chance you can execute and reproduce the error under a debugger?  Q: Have you run "ldd" on the command that's failing to exec to check for any shared dependencies?

Comment: it's failing absolutely consistently (at least the 20 or 30 times I've tried.  I'm digging into shared dependencies.  The command is another application that starts fine otherwise and will also start fine if the daemon is run directly on the console.  I'm starting to suspect that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't getting set for the startup script.

Comment: It's a good bet that the environment is not the same.  Maybe instrument your code to do a `printenv` (or equivalent) before running `execv`?

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem under a debugger like gdb, that can make things a *lot* easier for you. IMHO...

Comment: My best guess in this case is that `execv` is trying to execute a binary without absolute path, relying on environment's path. On some systems it can find the binary, on some not. Output of `strace` of the process would help a lot.

Comment: "execv() [...] returns 127" It's not supposed to. Are you sure it doesn't return -1? Check what `errno` contains after.

Comment: It clearly returns 127 both branches of the fork get this as the result.  Execv returns 127 as it fails, and after waitpid in the parent process, we get the result that it failed with 127.  The app is started with an absolute path.  Getting info with a debugger on a daemon as we fork a process that fails to launch might be tricky!  I'll try tomorrow to dump the environment to the log file, at least the library path.

Comment: Oh, nice.  The problem has now resolved itself after a rebuild of the software.  This will make it difficult to accurately describe a solution.

Comment: for the record, @Nemo, system("printenv > /home/me/env.txt") didn't output any helpful path information even once the solution I posted _did_ start to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem came back and I found that I had actually solved it, but that the solution took some time to work.

A particular library that seems to have been picked up by on other systems (possibly because the library was loaded as part of a driver for some hardware that's missing on the errant machine) was not being found by the dynamic linker.

Adding it to a config file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ didn't immediately help, but a few hours later and after a few reboots it did.

So:  *execv()* didn't launch an application, and instead returned 127 as a symptom of not finding a library.

the solution was to add the path to an appropriate file in */etc/ld.so.conf.d/*

For immediate satisfaction, run *ldconfig* to rebuild the cache.